# Asp.net MVC Text Editor pass long html code to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, text-editor

I wants to make a text editor for a site to allow user to write his own text or past text from another source to create pages (like wordpress for example).
To do that i chose Jquery-Te as text editor.

My problem is that when i copy/paste a text from wikipedia for example, i got a 404.15 error. I have read that i can do some changes on the RequestLimit but i can't know how long user text can be. I can set a limit to 400000 but if user enter 500000 he will get an error. Is there another way to allow user to pass a lot of text?

My second problem is Jquery-Te generates html and my text is in fact an html code. Sometimes i cant get error like "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client".

Can someone help me to do what i want?

I give you my code :

View :

```
<form action="SaveArticle" method="post">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Article.Titre)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Article.Contenu, new { @class = "editor" })
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-circle">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
</form>


<script>
    $(".editor").jqte();
</script>
```

Controller :

```
public ActionResult GestionDesPages(GestionDesPagesViewModel gdpvm)
        {
            return View(gdpvm);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveArticle(GestionDesPagesViewModel gdpvm)
        {
            Articles article = gdpvm.Article;
            article.Date = DateTime.Now;
            article.Auteur = "Pascal";

            db.Articles.Add(article);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return View("GestionDesPages");
        }
```

ViewModel :

```
public class GestionDesPagesViewModel
    {
        public Articles Article{get; set;}
    }
```

Model :

```
public partial class Articles
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Titre { get; set; }
    public string Contenu { get; set; }
    public string Auteur { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Actif { get; set; }
}
```

Sorry For Bad English.
Thanks.

**EDIT :**

Thank You Nava.
The solution given by Nava helped me to resolve all my problems.
I didn't said that i uses EntityFramework. To add [AllowHttp], I used the procedure defined in this the[Add annotation to Entity Framework Generated class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488005/entity-framework-database-first-regeneration-make-me-lose-manual-changes)

Comment: Can I sugest  the use of rich text editor ?                                                           https://www.nuget.org/packages/RichTextEditor/                                               or   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/830925/Integrating-TinyMCE-into-an-MVC-Project

Comment: Thanks. i will try it and make a choice between RTE and Jquery-Te

Comment: Jquery Te is a good choise also. good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow HTML to be inputted in your form and not get the "potentially dangerous" message add the `[AllowHtml]` attribute to `Contenu`

```
[AllowHtml]
public string Contenu { get; set; }
```

Keep in mind that when you display that field, you will probably want to Html encode to prevent a Cross site scripting problem

Comment: Thank you Nava. Very HelpFull.

Comment: Also i believe you also want to use html raw if you actually want to display that data in the view.